# VueJS - Template not rendering anything

Tags: vue.js

I am super new to vue js and I am trying to the switch toggle shown here: https://headlessui.dev/vue/switch

So here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Site</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7de28896bc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://coinbetix.test/css/app.css">

    <!-- Scripts -->
</head>
<body class="font-sans antialiased">
<div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
    
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <main>
        <div class="py-12 max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">

            <div class="bg-white px-4 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 sm:px-6">
                <div id="app">
                    <template>
                        <Switch
                            v-model="enabled"
                            :class="enabled ? 'bg-teal-900' : 'bg-teal-700'"
                            class="relative inline-flex items-center h-6 rounded-full w-11"
                        >
                            <span class="sr-only">Enable notifications</span>
                            <span
                                :class="enabled ? 'translate-x-6' : 'translate-x-1'"
                                class="inline-block w-4 h-4 transform bg-white rounded-full"
                            />
                        </Switch>
                    </template>
                </div>


                <form action="http://mysite.test/deposit" method="post">
                    <div class="w-1/2 mx-auto">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Izbs4W1YHkxWODGgop8J1cOqpDuH7W1N9VoBzK6z">                        <input type="hidden" name="coin" value="ETH">
                        <label for="coin" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Select Crypto</label>
                        <select class="block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 border-gray-300 rounded-md" name="coin" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option value="ETH"> Ethereum</option>
                            <option value="LTC"> Litecoin</option>
                            <option value="ADA"> Cardano</option>
                        </select>







                        <div id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text">
                            Your password must be 8-20 characters long, contain letters and numbers, and must not contain spaces, special characters, or emoji.
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100">Generate Deposit Address</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </main>
</div>

<script src="http://mysite.test/js/app.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
<script  type="module" src="/js/app.js">
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    import { Switch } from '@headlessui/vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            Switch,
        },
        setup() {
            const agreed = ref(false)

            return {
                agreed,
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

What is not rendered at all is that part:

```
                            <div id="app">
    <template>
        <Switch
            v-model="enabled"
            :class="enabled ? 'bg-teal-900' : 'bg-teal-700'"
            class="relative inline-flex items-center h-6 rounded-full w-11"
        >
            <span class="sr-only">Enable notifications</span>
            <span
                :class="enabled ? 'translate-x-6' : 'translate-x-1'"
                class="inline-block w-4 h-4 transform bg-white rounded-full"
            />
        </Switch>
    </template>
</div>
```

Any idea why it is not shown at all ?

Comment: do you see any errors?

Comment: @Amaarrockz nope.

Comment: You use `enable` as a v-model but never define it. You returned `agreed` from setup but never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your setup method with this code -

```
setup() {
    const enabled = ref(false)

    return {
       enabled,
    }
},
```

You used `enabled` in Switch component as `v-model` so you should replace your `agreed` variable with `enabled`.
Or you may use `agreed` in `v-model` instead of `enabled`.

Comment: No difference, still not working. Nothing appears.

Comment: Please check your vuejs version first if it doesn't work. Headless UI needs at least vuejs version 3. If vuejs version doesn't have a problem. Then inspect the `Switch` element from your browser and check if the CSS is working properly. 

`N.B. I think the CSS classes aren't working properly.`
I'm eagerly waiting to know if it's working on your side.

Comment: @headlessui/vue@1.4.2 and @vue/server-renderer@3.2.26 this is what I have. As I said I am very new to vuejs. The CSS classes are working because when I use the HTML version they show up. With the vuejs however nothing shows.

Comment: Can you share a git repo of your project?